# How to insert a linebreak in table caption?

Tags: captions

I want my table caption to look something like this

[image]

I tried `newline` and `\\`, but they did not work!

Is it possible to display the caption like above?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the `caption` package. `labelsep=newline` in combination with `labelfont=bf` should result in the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `caption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,
                     labelsep=newline,
                     singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{this is my caption text}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{this is my caption text this is my caption text this is my caption text this is my caption text this is my caption text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @leandriis

Answer (score 1):

Load `caption` and use  in the preamble

```
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bernard